# indesign VBS tranfer to VB.net

Tags: vb.net, adobe-indesign

Its the original text (VBS) in InDesign_ScriptingGuide:

```
Set myInDesign = CreateObject("InDesign.Application")
For myCounter = myInDesign.Documents.Length To 1 Step -1
myInDesign.Documents.Item(myCounter).Close idSaveOptions.idNo
Next
```

I make same changes and run in vb.net as below:

```
Dim myInDesign = CreateObject("InDesign.Application")
For myCounter = myInDesign.Documents.Length To 1 Step -1
myInDesign.Documents.Item(myCounter).Close(indesign.idSaveOptions.idNo)
Next
```

It's some error in myInDesign.Documents.Length. Length isn't member of Documents.

How can I get the number of indesign files was opened?

Comment: I am not familiar with the InDesign application but I see that Documents is plural which leads me to believe it is some sort of collection. Perhaps it needs an index to refer to a specific document which will have a .Length property.

Comment: place a break point on a line #2. Then when it is hit, put your mouse over `myInDesign` and see what you have there